# update Mysql table with values from another mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two tables in a mysql database. Memebers and ClassNumbers. Both tables have a paid year field and both have a code field. I want to update the paid year in the Members table with the values from the code numbers table Where code in members is the same as code in ClassNumbers.
I know this is probably nowhere near right but it might explain it a bit better.

UPDATE Members SET paidYear (THE VALUE OF PAID YEAR IN ClassNumbers) where cl_code == code

**Members**

id,

Paid year,

cl_code,

**ClassNumbers**

id,

paidyear,

code,

I came across this code when searching other answers I'm thinking it's something similar

```
UPDATE business b, people p
SET b.email = p.email
WHERE b.business_id = p.business_id
AND p.sort_order = '1'
AND b.email = ''
```

Comment: well u got the answer there... so what do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Members JOIN ClassNumbers ON Members.cl_code = ClassNumbers.code
SET    Members.paidyear = ClassNumbers.paidyear
```